# Facing difficulty in SQL databases

Tags: java, sql

If I have 150 projects in a solution and each project consists of 300 pages. How would I change a variable `xyz` from `int` to `string` and do the same in the stored procedures, tables and others without affecting the current functionality?

Comment: Does the database need to be backwards compatible with other code that expects `xyz` to be an int?  Or are you just looking for a general solution to stage the conversion of the type?  I assume you want to migrate `xyz` to be a string in your tables, correct?

Comment: ...I'm slightly afraid to ask, what information is _stored_ in `xyz`?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I change a variable xyz from int to string and do the same in the stored procedures, tables and others without affecting the current functionality?

I don't know of any magic that would do that, and which would also guarantee that there would be no hitches; i.e. that current functionality would not be affected.

The best I can suggest is that you do it carefully, one project at a time, carefully testing each project before moving to the next one.

And make sure that you don't modify the databases in-place.  For each project, clone the database and its stored procedures before you start.  That way, if you mess it up you haven't trashed the existing system / project.

---

The other point to make is that your "system" screams for some kind of automation and/or rationalization.  What you currently have sounds like it is an effort sink for doing whole-sale maintenance work.